# Regex to find first instant of numbers & letters

Tags: regex

Search string:

- 23 a-1b2c3d4 b-1b2c3d4
- a-1b2c3d4 b-1b2c3d4
- as a-1b2c3d4 b-1b2c3d4

I want regex to find the first set of characters that contain both numbers and letters. In the case above I would like only `a-1b2c3d4` as a result but I'm getting all instances of `b-1b2c3d4` as well.

I have this so far:

```
 \b(?=\S*?\d)(?=\S*?[a-zA-Z])\S+\b
```

Comment: what are you giving the regex to? and can the letters be of any casing or will they be hexadecimal?

Comment: Like this? `^.*?(?<!\S)(?=[^\s\d]*\d)([^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]\S*)` https://regex101.com/r/P9YO9H/1 What should be the match for `23 -1b2c3d4 b-1b2c3d4`

Comment: You may use: `\b(?=[^\s\d]*\d)([\d-]*[a-zA-Z]\S+).*` and grab capture group #1

Comment: Your regex [works](https://regex101.com/r/NnTIux/1), just do not use `g` flag.

Comment: Most programming languages allow you to specify whether you want all matches or just the first match of a regexp. E.g. PHP has `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()`. Python has `re.search()` and `re.findall()`. So if you only want the first match, use the appropriate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with an either-or block

```
[^\s]*(?:\d[^\s]*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][^\s]*\d)[^\s]*
```

This works by finding

- any leading non-whitespace blocks `[^\s]*`
- either a block of `[a-zA-Z][^\s]*\d` or `\d[^\s]*[a-zA-Z]`
- any trailing non-whitespace blocks `[^\s]*`

```py
>>> re.findall(
...   r"[^\s]*(?:\d[^\s]*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][^\s]*\d)[^\s]*",
...   "23 a-1b2c3d4 b-1b2c3d4 2-a aa--2 --2a 1_b ABC ABC.4"
... )
['a-1b2c3d4', 'b-1b2c3d4', '2-a', 'aa--2', '--2a', '1_b', 'ABC.4']
```

You can adapt `[a-zA-Z]` to include more "letter" values if you want to extend it beyond the ASCII charset or reduce it if you only really expect say hex `[a-f]`